# Regarding adding of Rectangle when mouse is clicked on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, mouse, frame

I am a beginner. I am trying to add filled rectangle or any other graphic on JFrame using multiple inner classes. I am getting debugging errors. What are the problems here?. If this is a wrong way. Please tell me how to do the same using JFrame and JPanel only.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class RainBow{

    JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        RainBow bow = new RainBow();
        bow.go();
    }

    public class Paint extends JPanel{
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);

        }
    }

    public void go(){
        frame.addMouseListener(new ListenMouse());
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class ListenMouse implements MouseListener{
        public void mosueClicked(MouseEvent a){
            Paint p = new Paint();
            frame.getContentPane().add(p);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}

}
```

Comment: What "debugging errors" have occurred?  How have you tried to fix them?

Answer (score 1):

The code posted has multiple problems. See this working example with explanations in comments.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RainBow {

    JFrame frame;
    boolean paintRectangle = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RainBow bow = new RainBow();
        bow.go();
    }

    public class Paint extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); // should always be done
            if (paintRectangle) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
            }
        }
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame(); // otherwise NPE
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.addMouseListener(new ListenMouse()); // add listner to paint
        frame.add(paint); // add paint at start-up
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // ensures JVM shuts down when frame is closed.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public class ListenMouse extends MouseAdapter {

        // this method is incorrectly spelled!
        public void mosueClicked(MouseEvent a) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            /* requires special handling to add components on the fly */
            //Paint p = new Paint(); 
            paintRectangle = true;
            frame.repaint(); // forces the Paint to be painted as well.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be nice to override `getPreferredSize`, but since they're using a `BorderLayout` and not using `pack` they won't see the effect of that

Comment: @MadProgrammer True. I decided to stop earlier than that, though, ir order to address the main problems with the code (including that as posted, it did not run past the `NPE`!).

Comment: Yep, better not overwhelm them in the past pass :P

Comment: why is there two mousClicked methods ?

Comment: *"..why is there two mousClicked methods ?"* Dude, you need to ***triple check*** your spelling. There is no `mousClicked` method, there **is** one `mosueClicked` method (like you originally spelled it) & there is an overridden `mouseClicked` method. Try copying all 3 of those to separate lines in a single text document and compare them letter for letter. Also note that if you'd used the `@Override` notation on the incorrectly spelled method, the compiler would have warned that it was incorrectly spelled (by showing a compile error).

Comment: I tried to run your code in eclipse its not working. Showing 2 debugging errors.

Comment: Just tried that exact code here in Netbeans & it's showing one warning in regard to not having `Add @Override Annotation` on the line `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {`. That warning doesn't stop it from compiling or running to show the red square when clicked. If I knew *exactly* what Eclipse is reporting, I might be able to help you with that. Make sure the code is tested n a fresh project though. **But don't expect me to spoon feed you.** SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk, and not a place to find a tutor.